# some icons are not visible some time

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Some icons are not visible some time(on bootstrap modal). It happens rarely.
All the icons are in a single file so these icons are loading.
I verified the html, All the tags are correctly closed.
If i inspect any element and change any css property(of any element) all the hidden icon shown immediately.

[image: Bold and italic icon missing]

[image: All the icons are visinle]

Bold , Italic and the cross icon on bootstrap modal are having this problem.

Html is made in JavaScript (string) and append to html bootstrap modal element.
Html is like :

```
<div class='padding0 pos-rel cursor-pointer inline-block block-width pop-btns toolbar-action both input'>
    <i class='jd-font-inherit color-inherit font-10 edit-text pos-rel toolbar-action icon-bBold both input' key='toggleClass@@bold'></i>&nbsp;
    <div class='popover fade top in jd-font-roboto dark-gray-pop no-bdrs edit-detail-popover'>
        <div class='arrow'></div>
        <div class='popover-content'>
            <span class='padding0 txt-white'>Bold</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class='padding0 pos-rel cursor-pointer inline-block block-width pop-btns toolbar-action text'>
    <i class='jd-font-inherit color-inherit font-10 edit-text pos-rel toolbar-action icon-aDown text' key='changeFont@@decrease-font'></i>&nbsp;
    <div class='popover fade top in jd-font-roboto dark-gray-pop no-bdrs edit-detail-popover'>
        <div class='arrow'></div>
        <div class='popover-content'>
            <span class='padding0 txt-white'>Decrease Font</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please, share your HTML, or give URL of the problem page.

Comment: How do you include font to the page?

Comment: we have our own icon created, we load the font file from our static server

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are using for eg.

1. if you are using bootstrap icons or font awesome icons, then you should not use cdn'.
2. if icons are locally in your drive then see the time of load then you can optimize the icons

Comment: We have our icons in local file, all the icons are in same file, but some particular icons have this problem.